# Can't Connect ClickHouse With JDBC Driver Using DBeaver

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver, clickhouse

I want to connect clickhouse with jdbc driver using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). My driver settings are:

> Driver Name: clickhouse
>
> Class Name: ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
>
> URL Template: jdbc:clickhouse://{host}:{port}

When I test the connection, it throws me an exception like this:

> ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseUnknownException: ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: xxx, port: 8123; error while read response Magic is not correct: 112

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: It would be perfect, if you show some code that you are trying to implement.

Comment: There is no code. I'm just triying to connect clickhouse database with DBeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My DBeaver version was old, I updated my version and its solved.

Comment: Is DBeaver version 4.2.6 old too? )